# grouping sibling div tags.

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

i have a page which consists of the following

```
<h3> </h3>
<div class="row1"></div>
<div ></div>
<div></div>

<h3> </h3>
<div class="row1"></div>
<div ></div>
<div></div>
```

now all i want is code that lets me group the sibling div tags as follows

```
<h3> </h3>
 div class="group1"> 
    <div class="row1"></div>
    <div ></div>
    <div></div>
 </div>

  <h3> </h3>
 div class="group2"> 
    <div class="row1"></div>
    <div ></div>
    <div></div>
 </div>
```

so iv taken a few appoaches but the most promising seems to be this line of code

```
 $( "#block-views-taxomony-view-block-1 .view-content  h3").nextUntil("h3").wrapAll("<div></div>");
```

but alas all its doing is throwing everything in a sigular div.   ps  i dont need a class for the group div, it just needs to be in a single div, because i want to use it for a accordion i built.  this should also be able to be done dynamically

Comment: sorry just so my group div isnt in a tag, just pretend its there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap it into a loop. Using wrap on 1 set will indeed take all `div` and wrap them in a single one. You need to do multiple set :

```
$( "#block-views-taxomony-view-block-1 .view-content  h3").each(function(){
    $(this).nextUntil("h3").wrapAll("<div></div>");
})
```